# What is the nickname for Michel?

Tags: surnoms

Is there a nickname for Michel (Michael) in French?

Back in the IRC days, when I introduced myself as Mike on a French channel, everyone called me "Mickey" for whatever reason.

Answer (score 10):

There is *Michou*, which is often used.

Comment: Le problème : Michou est le nom d'un gérant de cabaret parisien pour transformistes, figure médiatique toujours habillée en bleu, jusqu'aux verres de ses lunettes. Dans le monde du travail, il n'y a pas de Michou, sauf dans la bouche d'un homophobe agressif. On entend parfois Mimiche, mais c'est un des prénoms qui supporte mal l'utilisation des diminutifs.

Comment: @cl-r: Je vous remercie de me prévenir. Cette information est vraiment bon à savoir.

Comment: Heyy mon oncle se fait appeler Michou dans notre famille et on a jamais fais le lien avec l'homophobie.... :(

Comment: @LeSnip3R En famille, pas de problème, surtout si cela s'est fait de tout temps. Mais se faire appeler Michou par quelqu'un que l'on connaît à peine devant un auditoire d'étrangers peut mettre mal à l'aise : je recadre immédiatement toute personne (et surtout les collègues) qui utilise le diminutif de mon prénom en public, c'est aussi une question de connivence que l'on peut refuser, car malsaine.

Answer (score 7):

As with many french first names, you can make a nickname by keeping the first syllable and repeating it: *Mimi*.

Comment: Mimi is the more commonly used.

Comment: Mimi ne s'emploie qu'entre intimes, en famille, ou comme marque affectueuse pour un enfant. Autant on entend Fred pour Frédéric, autant, je vois mal quelqu'un appeler Mimi, Michel Rocard (premier ministre sous Mitterrand), ou tout autre adulte, sauf peut-être par des chansonniers. Entre collègues : "il faudrait en parler à Mimi" est possible et au cas par cas, mais pas par un étranger à l'équipe. J'ai entendu une fois Mickey, mais c'est plus par dérision, et jamais en face du Michel en question.

Comment: @cl-r: Selon mon expérience, votre observation vaut pour tous les surnoms. Je n'appelle pas Fred un Frédéric qui ne fait pas partie de mon cercle de proches.

Comment: @mouviciel dans l'environnement de travail, on entend souvent Dédé, Fred, Stef pour André, Frédéric ou Stéphane. En fait cela dépend de l'âge, mon jeune chef de service se fait appelé Fred par ses subordonnés sans problème, les relations professionnelles étant basées principalement sur la compétence technique ou chacun a trouvé la bonne distance vis-à-vis de l'autre. C'est en effet au cas par cas, mais cela est possible

Comment: Je suis québécois, pour moi le problème est que Mimi est le diminutif de *Mireille*, un prénom féminin.

Answer (score 5):

*Mitch* or *Mitch'* is sometimes used, mostly among teenagers and young adults.

Comment: Really ? I thought that sounded more American and stood for Mitchell...

Comment: Well, the fact that it sounds more American might be the very reason why it's used actually :)

Comment: I also heard *Mich'*, without the *t* consonant, a few times.

Answer (score -1):

Micah, A lot of my call my brother Micah and his name is Michael

Comment: *Michael* n'est pas un prénom français dans le sens où il n'existe pas dans les prénoms du calendrier, ou ceux donnés habituellement avant les années 50. L'officier d'état civil pouvait alors refuser d'enregistrer un prénom hors norme. Depuis les règlements se sont assouplis, et seul est exigé un prénom qui ne nuise pas au futur du nouveau né. en ce XXIe siècle, il n'est pas rare d'appeler son pote à l'anglo-saxonne *Mike*, par effet de mode ou pour s'intégrer dans un groupe.